# React children inside of factory

Tags: reactjs

I want to create mixin which would render some partial component which would be react component. I found out that I can't do something like `mixin_member: React.createClass({...})` because I need to use `React.createFactory()`

so I have following mixin:

```jsx
module.exports = function(tab_variable_name){
        return {
                handleOptionGroupChange(tab){
                        let new_state = {};
                        new_state[tab_variable_name] = tab;
                        this.setState(new_state);
                },
                propsToState(props){
                        let new_state = {tab_variable_name: tab_variable_name};
                        new_state[tab_variable_name+'s'] = Object.keys(props.data);
                        new_state[tab_variable_name] = Object.keys(props.data)[0];
                        return new_state;
                },

                componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
                        this.setState(this.propsToState(nextProps));
                },
                getInitialState(){
                        return this.propsToState(this.props);
                },

                Menu: React.createFactory(React.createClass({
                        render(){
                                return (
                                    <ul id="Steps">
                                            {this.props.parent.state[tab_variable_name+'s'].map((item) => (
                                                <li
                                                    className={item == this.props.parent.state[tab_variable_name] ? "active" : null}
                                                    onClick={() => {
                                                        let new_state = {};
                                                        new_state[tab_variable_name] = item;
                                                        this.props.parent.setState(new_state);
                                                }}
                                                >
                                                        {item}
                                                </li>
                                            ))}
                                    </ul>
                                );
                        }
                })),
                Panel: React.createFactory(React.createClass({
                        render(){
                                console.log(this.props.children);
                                return (
                                    <div id="Panel">
                                            {this.props.parent.state[tab_variable_name]}
                                            {this.props.children}
                                    </div>
                                );
                        }
                }))
        };
};
```

And I use it like this:

```jsx
const Options = module.exports = React.createClass({
        displayName: "Options",
        mixins: [require("./Tabs.Mixin")('options_group')],
        render(){
                return (
                    <div>
                            Options:
                            <Tabs_Menu parent={this} />
                            <Tabs_Panel parent={this}>
                                    <div>Selected tab: {this.state.options_group}</div>
                                    <div>First panel child</div>
                                    <div>Second panel child</div>
                                    <div>Third panel child</div>
                            </Tabs_Panel>
                    </div>
                );
        }
});
```

But i get this error:

```
Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Panel`.
```

When I put those components in separate files - variables, it works just fine. Also when i log this.props.children in console (in mixin components), logged object doesn't look like react component, it's just this:

[image: this.props.children]

So how can I access, or better, render children of such component?
Thank you.

Comment: Not the answer your looking for but perhaps you should consider composition using higher order components: https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/mixins-are-dead-long-live-higher-order-components-94a0d2f9e750#.5biblaju2

Comment: I've read that article but I don' think it's applicable in my situation.

Answer (score 0):

I went through react code and found out that not using `React.createFactory()` was right, despite console hint. But I also needed to add `autobind: false,` to my mixin object. Now everything works correctly, however I expect some issues because of turning autobinding off.